# Make an icon (button) apear when the text in a text-field is eddited and dissapear once clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

It is suprisingly hard to have an v-text-area with an appended (outer or not) button (icon) that appears only when the text inside the text-area is modified and disaper only once it is clicked on.

Here is my stripped code to show relevant info:

```
    <template>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-card>
          <v-row>
            <v-col>
              <v-card flat>
                  <v-col>
                    <v-text-field
                      dense
                      solo
                      name="requesterNameTextArea"
                      filled
                      hide-details
                      v-model="exceptionObj.requesterName"
                      :append-icon="showSaveIcon ? 'mdi-check' : null"
                      :flat="!showSaveIcon"
                      type="text"
                      @keydown="showSave"
                      @click:append="putException(exceptionObj), GoToException, hideSave"
                      @blur="hideSave"
                    >
                    </v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-card>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </template>

    <script>
    import ...
    export default {
      components: {
      },
      data() {
        return {
          showSaveIcon: false,
          exceptionObj: [],
        };
      },
      methods: {
        putException, //Api put command
        GoToException: function (item) {
          this.$router.push({
            name: "UniversalException",
            params: {
              id: item.exceptionId,
            },
          });
        },
        showSave() {
          this.showSaveIcon = true;
        },
        hideSave() {
          this.showSaveIcon = false;
        },
      },
      async mounted() { 
        this.exceptionObj = await getExceptionObj(this.ExceptionId);
      },
    };
    </script>
```

I basically tried every possible combination of event prop like thoses:

```
@keydown="showSave"
@change="showSave"
@focus="showSave"
@blur="hideSave"
@click:append="putException(exceptionObj), GoToException, hideSave"
```

And having multiple "commands" on a single @click command doesn't do anything else than the api command (like if props had priority over one another). The GoToException was to try and force a reload of the page in order to lose focus. Having the icon appended on outer or normal changes the behavior but I never succeded on obtaining the desired result.

Any idea on how to go around that problem would be apreciated. Especially infuriating as so many websites implement it and I have yet to find a way to do it ;_;

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it is simply impossible to use the

```
@click:append="putException(exceptionObj), hideSave"
```

But it is possible to use a new method like so:

```
SaveException() {
  putException(this.exceptionObj);
  this.hideSave();
},
```

And so, I ended up with a simple:

```
@click:append-outer="SaveException()"
```